# It is legal to reinstall OEM Localized Windows with English Windows?

Tags: windows, license, localization

I have bought Laptop with Windows 8 CZ (Czech localization). I would like to re-install the laptop with Windows 8 EN. It is legal to install English Windows if I bough Czech Windows? Where should I get installation media?

I installed English language to Czech Windows 8, the user interface has changed to English, but error messages and logs are still in Czech, which is very bad for programming and looking answers on stackoverflow. That is why I need real English Windows, not a localized Czech Windows.

Comment: I have Windows 8 Home Edition.

Comment: If you're a college/university student, you may be elligible for a free Windows 8.1 licence: http://onthehub.com/download/free-software/windows-8-1-pro-for-students/

Comment: Home edition is often the one people give without having to pay for an upgrade, so that makes sense.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is supposed to be free as an upgrade to any version of windows 8. It may not update the language files but it would be worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not student.

Comment: @qub1n - You mean *Windows 8 Core* I glazed over the fact your using Windows 8.  What you describe should be possible without reinstalling Windows 8 though.  I find it funny a comment attempting to help somebody with Windows 7 installed was upvoted though.

Comment: Yes, my laptop get updated automatically to Windows 8.1, but Czech not English.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Sorry it did not add languages.

Comment: Unless you have a `Single Language` license you should be able to accomplish this without reinstalling Windows 8.1.  I suggest you try creating your own English .iso using the [tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) Microsoft released

Comment: I upvoted the comment, because it brings me to this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media I will try it at evenening. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question of the legality of an action will entirely depend on the region a person is in and what is and is not allowed by that user's Windows license.  What is and is not allowed is well defined in the given Windows license in question which can entirely be different depends on the specific version of Windows the user is using.

Comment: @Ramhound - sounds reasonable enough to me - go ahead and close

Comment: @JeffClayton - Technically that was the close vote.  The comment was generated when I created "other" explanation for the close vote.  In other words the question if something is legal isn't the best question, the question certainly can be reworded to avoid the legality of the action, I just don't know if I want to be the one that does so.

Comment: @Ramhound ahh okay, that makes sense as well - the answer I gave is based on the installing of a different one, which fits his legality answer (a key is a key and has to match) - but legality issues are really not safe to answer for everyone on international sites like you mentioned.

Comment: @JeffClayton - There is nothing wrong with your answer.  I am also not the final word on anything.  What is possible and enforced and what is possible but not enforced are two entirely different things.

Comment: @Ramhound - appreciated, and such is reality.

Comment: You can always try it, and if it activates successfully then yes. I personally did that with my french Windows 7, and it activated just fine using an english ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I created ISO language of Windows 8 EN by [Microsoft Create Installation Media Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), installed the Windows, enter the product key provided by Dell and it just worked. Furthermore I have found that there is a list of languages (including English) on Windows recovery DVD provided by Dell.

Comment: Great research, thank you for posting your results - glad it was not an issue of licensing but a different option entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to be able to do that unless the key is the same. In other words, to install it you would need a valid license key (which you would have to purchase or steal). To be honest - the odds are that nobody would check because people would not expect to look for which language version you have, but that you have a licensed version of windows. It is better to be safe than sorry and purchase it to be officially following the rules.